# Android: how to remove an item from a listView and arrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a collection of items in an ArrayList. I add them to a customer adapter as follows:

```
this.m_adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.myitem,
    itemCart.m_items);
```

I have a delete button for each of these items in my list, but I am not sure how to connect the delete button's `onClick()` with the original item in the ArrayList. Can someone please explain how to do this or point me to a tutorial where I can read up on this?  Non-sarcastic/non-condescending responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution so far:

In the `getView()` method I do something like this:

```
deleteButton.setTag(position);
```

It looks like `getTag()` returns an Object.  So I converted the position int into an Integer object first.  It appears to be working.

In the `OnClickListener()` I do the following:

```
items.remove(index.intValue());
```

So far, so good.

Comment: So without the tags - you have no idea which button is clicked? It seems to me that you've overlooked some mechanism for figuring that out. Think about using the button's parent.

Answer (score 30):

You can call the `remove()` method on your `ArrayList`

```
itemCart.m_items.remove(<index of element to remove>);
this.m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And then you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter to update the ListView

Comment: Yes, but my problem is figuring out how to specify the index for that item?  I think I need to use setTag() originally then getTag() before removal but I'd like to see some sample code if possible.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have a context menu on a ListView with a delete button that I get the element from using what's essentially `item.getMenuInfo().id` (it's not that simple). Surely your buttons have indexes though.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the index of the element by simply noticed that a list view is a collection of child views (the rows of the list).

You can do something like this in your code:

(inside the getView() method, for example)

```
row.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        remove(listView.indexOfChild(view));
        return true;
    }
}
```

That is, the solution is simply use indexOfChild(View) method to get index of child view that user (long) pressed.

Comment: solution for Xamarin as well

Answer (score 4):

Following works for me:

```
/* Read values from resource into an array */
String[] strColorValues =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < strColorValues.length; i++) {
    list.add(strColorValues[i]);
}

ArrayAdapter adapterColors = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

adapterColors.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinnerColors.setAdapter(adapterPermissionLevels);
spinnerColors.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

/* Remove first element from the adapter and notify dataset changed. */
String item = spinnerColors.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
adapterColors.remove(item);
adapterColors.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Code.

```
  transfer.setItemPosition(position, items.get(position).getAddMode());
```

the transfer here is the instance of the main class. everytime i click the deletebutton, it then pass the position of the that item on the list in this line.

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
          if (v == null) {
              final Context context = getContext();
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_layout, null);
          }

          ItemEntry item = items.get(position);
          if (item != null) {
                    TextView textViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                    ImageView imageViewDelete = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDeleteIcon);

                    imageViewDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {                   
                                transfer.showDialog(4);                             
                                transfer.setItemPosition(position, items.get(position).getAddMode());
                        }
                  });

          if (textViewName != null) {
                    textViewName.setText(item.getItemName());
          }

          if(imageViewDelete != null) {
              imageViewDelete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
          }
      }
      return v;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove by position:**

```
mainAdapter.remove(mainAdapter.getItem(position));
```

**Such as the last one:**

```
mainAdapter.remove(mainAdapter.getItem(mainAdapter.getCount() - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these codes of lines it was very helpful for me

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use context menu, then you can get
AdapterContextMenuInfo and this structure gives index and id of clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can get the index (or position) of a clicked item in the ListView as follows:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        listview.remove(listview.getItem(position).toString());
    }
}
```

So you need to listen for clicks on Views and then take the index from that.