# Android: Remove item (ListView)

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want to remove an item from `ListView`, but I don't know how can I do it.

This is my code...

```
public void FLYNOTE_refresh() {
    int i;
    SharedPreferences Pref = getSharedPreferences("nnote", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //созаётся файл настроек "nnote" и туда барыжиться вся хня
    key = Pref.getInt("number", 0); 
    key++;
    String lv_arr[] = new String[key];

    for (i = 0; i < key; i++) {
         lv_arr[i] = Pref.getString("n" + i, "none");           
    }

    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(key));

    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

I want to remove an item with `0 id`,guide me to do that.

Comment: Where you want to remove the element 

((ArrayAdapter)list.getApadter()).remove(list.getApadter().getItem(index));((ArrayAdapter)list.getApadter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: where you want to remove 0 id? in FLYNOTE_refresh function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to display item 0, simply adjust the size of `lv_arr` and change your for-loop:

```
public void FLYNOTE_refresh() {
    int i;
    SharedPreferences Pref = getSharedPreferences("nnote", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //созаётся файл настроек "nnote" и туда барыжиться вся хня
    key = Pref.getInt("number", 0); 
    String lv_arr[] = new String[key]; // One item smaller without "n0" 

    key++;
    for (i = 1; i < key; i++) {
        // Skip "n0" like this
        lv_arr[i - 1] = Pref.getString("n" + i, "none");           
    }

    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(key));

    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
    listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

If you want to remove items while the app is running I suggest using a `List<String>` rather than a `String[]`:

```
public void FLYNOTE_refresh() 
{
    int i;
    SharedPreferences Pref = getSharedPreferences("nnote", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //созаётся файл настроек "nnote" и туда барыжиться вся хня
    key = Pref.getInt("number", 0); 
    key++;
    lv_arr = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    for (i = 1; i < key; i++) {
        lv_arr.add(Pref.getString("n" + i, "none"));           
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            lv_arr.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete an item from ListView as:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapterlist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr);
     listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
     adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
     listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    adapter1.remove(position);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

and you can see these posts for removing an item from ListView:

[Remove ListView items in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android)

[Android: how to remove an item from a listView and arrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698386/android-how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-listview-and-arrayadapter)

Comment: adapter1.remove() is "String object"

Comment: remove() take an integer not string

Comment: I must agree with user1468102, [ArrayAdapter<class T>.remove(T object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) means remove() only takes an object of the ArrayAdapter's referenced class, also ArrayAdapter.remove() is essentially a shortcut for `lv_arr.remove()` which doesn't exist for `String[]`.