# ListView: Remove an item

Tags: android, listview

I have created [a similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112953/android-remove-item-listview), but I have a problem:

```
String lv_arr[] = new String[key];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterlist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr);

listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView1.setAdapter(adapterlist);

adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapterlist.remove(adapterlist.getItem(0));
adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The item in ListView does't get removed using the code below. I looked for a solution for days.

```
adapterlist.remove(String object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the objects from your collection and then call `adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload the collection.

```
lv_arr.removeAt(0);
adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
```