# Remove All items (visible and not visible) Custom listview Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have problem in my code.I want remove all items in custom `listview` with this code :

```
public void delete_all()
{
    int count = getCount();
    if(count>0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
          {
              data.remove(data.get(i));
          }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}
```

but the result, just **items visible** where deleted ,
example : there **count** = 5 item , the result just 3 **items visible** are deleted, and 2 items in not deleted,

```
data.remove(data.get(i));
```

i try too change with `data.remove(i);`
i same result;

and logcat of that code is

```
> 04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     ... 11 more
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111): **Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2**
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at com.droidersuin.imagelistfromurl.LazyAdapter.delete_all(LazyAdapter.java:60)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     at com.droidersuin.app.SearchActivity.search(SearchActivity.java:306)
04-15 13:07:58.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2111):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Take a look at this link..May it will help you...[link1][1]


and [link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112953/android-remove-item-listview

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove all Item then just call `clear()` instead of `remove()`. Like this

```
data.clear(); // this will clear your list
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: Never ever remove item in loop with using same object size as like means it will change you size of you `list/arraylist` so you getting unpredictable size on each iterator. You can either use store in another list and then use

```
List<String> yourSelectData; store your data in this at iterate time then remove after loop complete


data.removeAll(yourselectData); // using this you can remove collection of element from list
```

Comment: Thank's mr.pratik , i have 
change my code with 
`if(count>0)
      {
       // data.removeAll(); if i change with this, is error, sugesstion avaible
       data.removeAll(data);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

but still other error in logcat my code :( ,

Comment: I think you still doing some mistake don't use the same list object and when you want to remove all just use clear() and for selected item like user select by tap or by checked boxed that you have to stored in another list object and passed to the original list in removeAll()

Comment: Hai.... Thank... i other mistake other code... data.clear() is work :)

THANKS :)